# How to make windows terminal above all other windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I do have a .bat script and at some point I want to make it active and ask user for input. Is it possible to make this window active and above any other window on my screen.

Powershell will also work for me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

With Powershell you can prompt a Inputbox, which will be on top.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic')
```

`[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Message", "Tile", "Default answer")`